# Is there a way to disable the printing of the additional header and footer information in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, pdf, utf-8

We were using htmldoc but unfortunately it does not support UTF-8.

I tried using the Mozilla Firefox command-line printPDF extension but it placed the URL on the upper right of every page of the PDF which unfortunately isn't acceptable because these files are client-facing.

I've also heard of [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) but it simply costs too much.

Is there a way to disable the printing of the additional header and footer information in Firefox? In about:config I found some preferences that looked similar to what I wanted—headerright and so on—and cleared them out, but it's still appearing.

Comment: What type of html documents are you converting? Manuals, Catalogs with a lot of graphics, etc.

Comment: Table-based HTML 4.01 with a handful of images for item descriptions that go to clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did come across header and footer configuration iptions options in the firefox gui to remove your troublesome headers.  I wonder if you set these, the printPDF extension will work as you want them?

Comment: I could do the same as well - just do not have English firefox to tell you for sure that this is called "format printing" or something else.

Comment: Yes, disabling it in the GUI turned it off on the rendered PDFs.